# Inserting dictionary contents into string to extract query plans

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am using PostgreSQL 12 and Python 3.8. I want to work out ways that make use of the JSON-compliance in PostgreSQL.

My Problem is that I get an error when executing the select statement. In order for the index to trigger I need to use the operator `@>` and this operator expects something like this `'{"age":"37"}'`.
I just can't get this dictionary inside the query string...

I have the following table:

```
create table json_table1 (
    p_id int primary key,
    first_name varchar(20),
    last_name varchar(20),
    p_attribute jsonb,
    quote_content text
)
```

This is the Python code:

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import RealDictCursor
import json

def main():
    connection_string = " "
    connection = psycopg2.connect(connection_string)
    cursor = connection.cursor(cursor_factory=RealDictCursor)
    cursor.execute("set search_path to public")


    test_dict = {
            'age':'37'
    }


    sql="explain analyze select * from json_table1 where p_attribute @> '{'age':%s}'"
    cursor.execute(sql, (test_dict['age'],))

    result = cursor.fetchall()
    with open('with_gin.json', 'w') as output:
        json.dump(result, output, indent=4)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PATH", line 27, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/PATH", line 19, in main
    cursor.execute(sql, (test_dict['age'],))
  File "C:\PATH", line 243, in execute
    return super(RealDictCursor, self).execute(query, vars)
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "age"
LINE 1: ...select * from json_table1 where p_attribute @> '{'age':'37'}...
```

This query works inside pgAdmin4:

```
explain analyze select * from json_table1
where p_attribute @> '{"age":"37"}'
```

I wish to insert the dictionary contents dynamically but first it needs to work with the static dict.

How do I get the dictionary contents, preferably key as well as its value, in the sql string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let psycopg2 handle the parameters for you:

```
import json
...
sql="explain analyze select * from json_table1 where p_attribute @> %s"
cursor.execute(sql, (json.dumps(test_dict),))
print(cursor.mogrify(sql, (json.dumps(test_dict),)))
```

Output:

```
explain analyze select * from json_table1 where p_attribute @> '{"age": "37"}'
```